# Show price with customer group vat on product page

Tags: customer, group

I created an user group, it is associated with a different tax class ("reduced") compared to standard clients.

When I open a product  (I'm logged in as a user of the "reduced" fee), I see the price with the standard fee. 
But if I add product to cart, I see the right price, with the reduced fee.

To show the price in use product:

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_product->getFinalPrice(),false,false);?>
```

How do I show the correct price also in the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), true);
```

See

```
/**
 * Get product price with all tax settings processing
 *
 * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param   float $price inputed product price
 * @param   bool $includingTax return price include tax flag
 * @param   null|Mage_Customer_Model_Address $shippingAddress
 * @param   null|Mage_Customer_Model_Address $billingAddress
 * @param   null|int $ctc customer tax class
 * @param   null|Mage_Core_Model_Store $store
 * @param   bool $priceIncludesTax flag what price parameter contain tax
 * @return  float
 */
public function getPrice($product, $price, $includingTax = null, $shippingAddress = null, $billingAddress = null,
                         $ctc = null, $store = null, $priceIncludesTax = null, $roundPrice = true)
{
```